# Using lodsb to move a byte into another address using inline c

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I'm learning inline assembly in c and I'm trying to load a byte into another variable so I can eventually get into working with strings.

My current code took a pretty simple approach with my comments showing my logic below:

```c
char load = 't', ret;

asm volatile(
  "mov $1, %%esi;"  /* move arg 1 (load) into %esi */
  "lodsb;"          /* load one bite from %esi into %eax */
  : "=a" (ret)      /* ret in %eax */
  : "S" (load)      /* load in %esi */
);
```

However, my output gives me a seg fault. Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Operands use `%` not `$`.  So you just put an integer `1` into ESI and used it as a pointer.  Use a debugger.  (Also, you already asked for it in ESI/RSI, so if you'd written it correctly it would have compiled to a useless `mov %esi, %esi`.  Also, if you'd used `"S" (&load)` to get the *address* of the char in a register, you still need a `"memory"` clobber - [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259))

Comment: (I closed this before I noticed you were passing a char *value* as a pointer instead of an address.  After fixing this bug, you'd still segfault from effectively doing  `*(char*)'t'`.

Comment: Oh, and also `lodsb` modifies ESI/RSI so you need a `"+S"(load)` operand or a dummy output with a matching constraint.  Input operands are assumed to be unmodified.  (Like source operands for a single instruction; GNU C inline asm constraints are designed to describe a single instruction to the optimizer.  They are the same constraints that GCC's internal machine-description files use to describe the real instruction set.)